# Multiplying values in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, exec, dynamic-sql, execute

Using dynamic SQL I want to insert two columns into a table. The second column will be calculated using two parameters that are passed in from another stored procedure. I know I can do the below using sp_execute but wondered if I could do similar using just EXEC

```
   DECLARE @vsql nvarchar(max)

   DECLARE @p1 numeric
   SET @p1 = 5

   SET @vsql = ' Select PORTFOLIO_CODE, (@p1 * @p1) as leverage
   INTO greg
   from ssc.slh
   select * from greg'

   Exec sp_executesql
   @stmt = @vsql,
   @params = N'@p1 as numeric',
   @p1 = @p1
```

Can I do this using Exec? The below doesn't seem to work does the multiply operand need to be a sting literal?

DECLARE @vsql nvarchar(max)

```
   DECLARE @p1 numeric
   SET @p1 = 5

   SET @vsql = ' Select PORTFOLIO_CODE, (' + @p1 * @p1 + ') as leverage
   INTO greg
   from ssc.slh
   select * from greg'

   Exec sp_executesql
```

Comment: why do you use dynamic sql?

Comment: the reason it doesn't work is that you need to convert the result to (n)varchar(x) in order to concatenate it with the rest

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need dynamic SQL? You can just use the variable in your query output

```
DECLARE @p1 numeric = 5;

Select 
    PORTFOLIO_CODE, (@p1 * @p1) as leverage
from ssc.slh
```

EDIT:
For dynamic column mapping. 
Both @p1 and @p2 are column names you want to multiply?

```
DECLARE 
    @p1 nvarchar(200) = 'myFirstColumnName',
    @p2 nvarchar(200) = 'mySecondColumnName',

DECLARE @vsql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT PORTFOLIO_CODE, ([' + @p1 +'] * ['+ @p2 + ']) leverage from ssc.slh';
PRINT @vsql;
Exec sp_executesql @vsql;
```

Comment: The problem I now have is @p1 is a string which represents a column name  and I want to now multiply that column name (string also) by another which is stored in p2. When I try to multiply these two columns togher like p1 * p2 as column (which will contain numerics) I get the following error 'Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for multiply operator' any advice?